# build triggered from another job hangs on "Waiting for next available executor on..."

Tags: jenkins

I have a job that works on a specific executor and at some point triggers another job, wait until this job ends and then continues.
The problem is, that the triggered job won't start and says"Waiting for next available executor on [executor_name]".

I think it happens because the triggered job thinks that the executor is "busy" becuse the first job is still running (although it doesn't do anything and just waits for the triggered job).

Here's how I trigger it:

```
        stage('Run tier1 tests') {
            when {
                expression { env.*****.toBoolean() }
            }
            steps {
                build(
                    job: 'test-******',
                    parameters: [
                        string(name: '*****', value: env.***),
                        string(name: '*****', value: '***'),
                        string(name: '*****', value: '0.20')
                    ],
                    propagate: false
                )
            }
        }
```

How can I make the triggered job run immediately?

Answer (score 2):

Increase the number of executors. The maximum number of Jenkins jobs is dependent upon what you set as the limits in the master and slaves.

For the master, this is set in Manage Jenkins > Configure System > # of executors

For the slaves (nodes), it is set in Manage Jenkins > Nodes > (each node) > Configure > # of executors

Comment: Can you please guide me on Jenkin CI-CD configuration for the android. I just want to config my remote server to create my apk and testing,Please help me on it Thanks

Comment: Please create a new question with detailed information

Comment: Please check my latest question on Jenkin. Please help me to short out from the problem  Link :- https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958